# How to authenticate using imap with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, imap

I've been looking around for an imap plugin for rails or devise.

I've found this one notably https://github.com/joshk/devise_imapable but it is too old.

How would I go about rolling my own authentication using something like imap?

Should I be modifying ryan bates authentication from scratch?

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch